# wordpress: automatic logout

Tags: wordpress, security

I have a wordpress site an recently when I want to login to my site it login successfully but after a couple of seconds it kick me out.

It happens with all of my accounts but it does not happen when I login from another device. Can anyone help me with what is happening here? And can give me any solution for it.

I am using impreza for my theme. I tried using idle user logout plugin to make user stay longer, my wordpress address and site address in setting is equal.

I tried adding this code to my function.php file function:

```php
wpse108399_change_cookie_logout( $expiration, $user_id, $remember ){
    if( $remember && user_can( $user_id, 'manage_options' ) ){
        $expiration = 3156000;// yes, I know this is 1 minute
    }
    return $expiration;
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration','wpse108399_change_cookie_logout', 10, 3 );

if ( ! defined( 'US_ACTIVATION_THEMENAME' ) ) {
    define( 'US_ACTIVATION_THEMENAME', 'Impreza' );
}
```

And this to my wp-config.php:

```php
define('WP_HOME','http://www.mosaddeghian.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.mosaddeghian.com');
```

Comment: Why do you want to be logged out after 1 minute? You should check the cookies in your browser's dev-tools and see if they're set to the right domain (also protocol).

Comment: `$expiration` is the time in seconds, so it's actually `3156000 / 60 = 52600` minutes. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/auth_cookie_expiration/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my problem is solved.
the problem was my domain, some of my links was http and some of them https and when you move to another page it would kick you out.
thanks everybody for help